# Test if field is EMPTY and NOT a number

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am a beginner JS student and attempting to do some form validation and I am struggling with it. I am currently suffering from covid so my brain may not be functioning and thinking through this properly but I need some help.

Basically what I am trying to test is that the "name" field of my form isn't blank AND that a number has not been input. I can get the blank part to check just fine but the number part is throwing me off. Here is the code I am working with.

```
function validateForm() {
  let x = document.forms["contact_form"]["myName"].value;
  if ((x == "") && (typeof x == 'number')) {
    alert("Name must be filled out properly.");
    return false;
  }

}
```

Following suggestions.. It would seem I am not accessing form data properly. Here is the form data I am attempting to access:

```
<form class="contact_form" method="put" action="confirmation.html">
    <label for="myName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="myName" id="myName" required />
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: `document.forms["contact_form"]["myName"].value` will _never_ be a number. It will _always_ be a string.

Comment: Does your form not have a closing tag `</form>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `&&`, condition is guaranteed to evaluate `false`. You should use OR (`||`) operator here.

Also, the the type of the value of `x` is string always string, you have to cast the value to number before the comparison, you can do so by prefixing `+` to the variable:

```
if ((x == "") || (typeof +x == 'number')) {
```

Though, I will suggest you to use use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

```
if ((x == "") || !isNaN(x)) {
```

**Demo:**

```js
function validateForm() {
  let x = document.forms["contact_form"]["myName"].value;
  if ((x == "") || !isNaN(x)) {
    alert("Name must be filled out properly.");
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<form name="contact_form">
  <input name="myName">
  <button onclick="return validateForm()">Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: sorry I posted my latest iteration of code i was working through. Ive tried using || a couple times and it still is failing. Tried what you suggested as well and it processes it normally. 
Bit annoying lol. Upon further investigation..i dont think im accessing the form information properly.. here's my form data:

Comment: @VeritasCurat, I have added demo code using `isNaN()`, please check:)

Comment: hey perfect! thaqt did exactly what i needed. thank you so much for the help!